# Making an organized rendering class

Tags: java, lwjgl, architecture

I'm using LWJGL (opeengl wrapper for Java) and Don't know how to make a renderer class for OpenGL. So In Immediate mode rendering I'd do a method like this to draw quadralaterals.

```
public static void drawQuad(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
    glVertex2f(x, y + height);
    glEnd();
}
```

Now that I want to use OpenGL 3+ , how can I organize code like [this](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_with_DrawArrays) into a static rendering class I can call methods like `Renderer.drawRect(x,y, width, height);`? Or if I can make something like a spriteBatch class.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're asking how to learn OpenGL, that's too broad. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of opengl 3+ tutorials out there. Since LWGJL is a thin wrapper, it doesn't matter what language they are in you should be able to adapt them easily. check those out:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/index.php?page=tutorials&series=1

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, actually. All you need is to replace the immediate mode draw calls with a [Vertex Buffer Object - VBO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object).

However, updating the VBO at every `drawQuad()` would be very inefficient. The optimal approach would be to batch the vertexes in a system-side vertex array and then update the VBO once per-frame before rendering. I'm not very familiar with Java, but in a Java-like pseudocode, this could look something like this:

```
class Renderer {

    // The OpenGL VBO handle. Initialize it somewhere, like
    // in a class constructor or application startup method.
    GLuint quadVBO;

    // A growable array of 2D points, for the vertexes of quadrilaterals.
    Array<Point2> quadVerts;

    // "Drawing" doesn't really draw anything, it just adds one more quad to the batch.
    void drawQuad(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        quadVerts.push(Point2D(x, y));
        quadVerts.push(Point2D(x + width, y));
        quadVerts.push(Point2D(x + width, y + height));
        quadVerts.push(Point2D(x, y + height));
    }

    // This will actually perform the OpenGL draw calls.
    void flushBatch() {
        if (quadVerts.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        // Bind the buffer:
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);

        // Then update the VBO data (use GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW since data is transient):
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVerts.size() * sizeof(Point2D), quadVerts.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        // TODO: Perform a draw call, look into `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`
        // if you plan on using an Index Buffer.

        // Clear the batch after it was drawn, for the next frame:
        quadVerts.clear();
    }
}
```

To learn more about OpenGL Vertex Buffer Objects, check these two tutorials:

- [OpenGL Vertex Buffer Object (VBO)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html)
- [VBO Indexing](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/)